# Can't boot from usb 3 port (Asus p6x58d-e)

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, bios

When entering the boot menu (F8) on boot, I can't see devices in my USB 3 slots. As soon as I move the thumb drive to the USB 2 slots it boots fine.

Thumb drive is a SanDisk Extreme 64gb USB 3.0 running Ubuntu 14. (though this is irrelevant as no USB's are recognized from boot menu or in bios when in the USB 3 slots).

USB 3 is turned on in bios, and within windows the USB 3 slots function perfectly at USB 3 speeds.

I just updated the bios to the latest version, but still no luck. Motherboard is an Asus p6x58d-e.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with my high end DELL workstation.  Apparently the drivers for the USB3 ports are not contained in the BIOS and must be loaded with the operating system.  In fact, if I have to start the rescue system in Windows, I have to load the USB3 drivers if I need to access anything on the USB3 ports.

So I think that you're out of luck here in getting your USB3 ports working prior to operating system support.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of this. Apparently it is common to omit USB 3 support from boot as the drivers take up a fair bit of memory. I'll wait to see if anyone else can shed some light, otherwise I'll give you the tick.